# División incorrecta

Tags: sql, postgresql

disculpen, estoy teniendo problemas con la división de mi base de datos, tengo mi tabla que tiene estos valores
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y estoy aplicando estas operaciones
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y me esta dando valores incorrectos en la división dejando varios campos en 0 cuando deberíamos de tener valores del 80%, 70% ,etc., este problema solo lo tengo con las columnas weekly, los total me salen todos los valores correctos.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Estás dividiendo enteros. Para obtener el resultado que esperas, usa tipos de datos que acepten decimales.

Comment: Como dice @LuisCazares debes hacer un casteo a tipos de datos decimales por ejemplo `columna::numeric`

Comment: Muchas gracias @LuisCazares, si me sirvió, como las otras columnas me realizo la operación sin problemas no pensé que fuera eso. Muchas gracias